# Wake up TV once browser webpage is changed/updated

Tags: vnc

Currently, using the Pi as a display for our firehouse alerting. [image]

What coding can I use to have the screen asleep but once the website is updated with a new call it wakes up the screen. I disabled screen sleep right now but don't want to burn out the LED tv.

Comment: You could look into CEC commands: http://elinux.org/CEC_%28Consumer_Electronics_Control%29_over_HDMI

Answer (score 1):

OK.  Here is the issue.  You've got software running on the Raspberry Pi that is your browser.  You didn't tell us which one you were using.  For this solution it doesn't really matter. This browser gets updates from the web server every so often because of dispatch.  These updates are pushed to the browser and you see the new call info.  Let's hope I got that part right.  What you'd like to have happen is after some predetermined time, the screen shuts off. (Let's say 2 hours) but when a new call comes and the browser refreshes the screen, you'd like the screen to come alive again (for 2 hours) to display the new info.

Your problem is with getting the browser to communicate with the pi display that it should turn on again.  There are no (easy) ways of getting that done.  I'd just let your browser do what a browser does and refresh the display as necessary.

You almost need another program that behaves like a browser (wget/curl) that can get the current web page and see if it has changed.  If it has changed, then let this program issue the turn on command to the TV/Display (see the CEC answer above for details) and start the (example time) 2 hour timer.  At the end of the 2 hours, go get the web page to see if it has changed, if it has, reset the 2 hour timer.  There's a loop there for you.  See it?  If it hasn't changed, then turn off the display and start the next loop of looking every (you pick - 2 minutes) to see if the web site has changed, if it has go to the first loop.  I'm assuming you'll want this loop to be much shorter so that when the web site changes the display turns back on right away.

I'd see if there were something on the web page like a call number that changes for each call.  Then after wget retrieves the web page you can keep track of the last call number and if there is a different/higher call number then there was a change.  The call number will probably be in the same location of the web page each time.  We'd like something predictable.

You'll need other help getting the script/program that retrieves the web page working and starts up when the Pi is booted.  There are other questions/answers here that cover that.

You might consider python for the app to retrieve the web page and check if it has changed.  There are many libraries available for that language.  I haven't checked but there is probably an interface to the CEC code/library in python.

Good luck with this and I hope you get it running!

(Just another Fire Fighter)